# GraphDB to php - addition/multiplication

Tags: php, sparql, graphdb

When I try to do addition/multiplication etc in php with GraphDb query results, I get the error below and don't know why. If this matters, in GraphDb, the values contain the "^^xsd:integer".

```
$generalTotal = 0;
$sql = "PREFIX c: <http://chinde.ro#>
        select ?titlu ?numeAutor ?pret ?nrBuc ((?pret * ?nrBuc) as $total) where {
            GRAPH c:Vanzari {
                ?idV c:carte ?idCarte.
                ?idV c:bucati ?nrBuc.
                ?idV c:idTranz c:'.$idTranzactie.'.
            }
            GRAPH c:Carti {
                ?idCarte c:titlu ?titlu.
                ?idCarte c:autor ?idAutor.
                ?idCarte c:pret ?pret.

            }
            GRAPH c:Autori {
                ?idAutor c:numeAutor ?numeAutor.
            }
        }";

$res = $client->query($sql);
foreach($res as $row){
   print "Total: ".$row->total;
   $generalTotal = $generalTotal + $row->total; // <-- errors appears cause of this
}
print $generalTotal;
```

> Notice : Object of class EasyRdf_Literal_Integer could not be
>   converted to int in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\LICENTA2\admin\componenteAdmin\comenzi.php on line 107

How would I go about this? Should I make a subquery where I take the results from the first query and add all the values of the $total's into a new parameter? Or is there a simple way to make the query int's recognised by php?

Comment: managed to get what i wanted with a subquery but i still would like to know if there are other ways maybe more direct to get the additon/multiply etc of query results

Comment: You would have to get the value from the literal object like this: `$row->total->getValue()`

Comment: @reiner_zuphall thanks a lot :) that's what i needed